# import mysql database to wamp server

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-connection, wamp

I am newbie using php and wamp. I am trying to use a mysql db with the wamp server. I am really confused on what the right steps are. Should I put the sql file in the/www folder or what is the way to go? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. left click wamp -> phpmyadmin
2. select database then click import (top right)
3. locate the database and click go.

Answer (score 0):

Via command line: http://www.ibsteam.net/blog/web-development/how-import-sql-file-within-wamp-environment-using-command-line

Answer (score 0):

If you just started I would recommend using phpmyadmin, which comes with wamp. Just run your main localhost www page, select phpmyadmin from there and use import. It's like uploading a file though www, you don't have to place it in any specific directory.